# What is lucene's tokenFilters order?

Tags: filter, lucene, analyzer

I have a question about the lucene's tokenfilters order. For example if I want to have following filters, what is lucene's order of using these filters?

1- LowerCaseFilter
       Cats  =>  cats

2- TrimFilter 
       Cats!  =>  Cats

3- StopFilter
       a cat  =>  cat

4- LengthFilter

5- StemmerFilter

6- SynonymFilter

I could not find any document explaining this sequence.

Answer (score 0):

Ordering of the filters depends on your needs.  However, your ordering seems reasonable.

Should note, I don't believe `TrimFilter` does what you specify.  `TrimFilter` trims whitespace from the token, not punctuation.  Most Tokenizers render this filter unnecessary.

TrimFilter and LowerCaseFilter would generally be used early, so that filter that operate on the content of words don't have to deal with casing or whitespace.

StopFilter and LengthFilter operate similarly, and I would generally use them before stemming.  Words removed by StopFilter usually are pretty atomic, and so applying it before the Stemmer makes sense.  Applying these filters after the stemmer could result in losing meaningful stems you hadn't intended.  If you *do* want your StopFilter to operate on stemmed words, it would need to come after the Stemmer, of course.

Whether SynonymFilter comes after the Stemmer definitely depends on your needs.  SynonymFilter following the Stemmer would generally be more useful, but will require you define the Synonyms using their stemmed forms